# What is the best way to pass a (temporary?) std::string to a function that uses it to construct an object that takes a copy?

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics, stdstring

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string s;
  Foo(std::string s_) : s(s_) { }
};

Foo* f(std::string s)
{
  return new Foo(s);
}
```

where `f()` can be called with an lvalue or rvalue `std::string`, or with a `char const*` causing a temporary (but that's the same as an rvalue I resume). For example:

```
int main()
{
  f("test");
  f(std::string());
  std::string s("test");
  f(std::move(s));
  std::string s2("test");
  f(s2); // This MUST cause one copy.
}
```

Only in the last case one copy is really needed.
In all other cases I'd like that no copy is made at all and the `std::string` is constructed just once (into the allocated `Foo`).

Is this possible? If so, how would the signature of `f()` look like?

EDIT:

Using [Tracked](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwds/blob/master/tracked.h) from [cwds](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwds) I created a little test program with a `string` class that prints when it is constructed, moved etc. For the main() function please see this [blob](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-statefultask-testsuite/blob/577136abe936444c8d1a6c8e1752f0652d1c9661/src/tracked_string.cxx).

The program as-is above gives the following output:

```
NOTICE  : Calling f("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string0*
TRACKED :     string1*(string0)
TRACKED :     string2*(string1)
TRACKED :     string1~
TRACKED :     string0~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string2~
NOTICE  : Calling f(string())... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string3*
TRACKED :     string4*(string3)
TRACKED :     string5*(string4)
TRACKED :     string4~
TRACKED :     string3~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string5~
NOTICE  : Constructing s("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string6*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
NOTICE  : Calling f(std::move(s))... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string6=>string7*
TRACKED :     string8*(string7)
TRACKED :     string9*(string8)
TRACKED :     string8~
TRACKED :     string7~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string9~
NOTICE  : Constructing s2("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string10*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
NOTICE  : Calling f(std::move(s))... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string11*(string10)
TRACKED :     string12*(string11)
TRACKED :     string13*(string12)
TRACKED :     string12~
TRACKED :     string11~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string13~
NOTICE  : Leaving main()...
TRACKED : string10~
TRACKED : string6~
```

Which, as expected, shows a lot of copying.

Using max66's first suggestion, see [this change](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-statefultask-testsuite/commit/b847f97f60daac0b38ff883817b307d4b2b173c3) I get the following output:

```
NOTICE  : Calling f("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string0*
TRACKED :     string0=>string1*
TRACKED :     string1=>string2*
TRACKED :     string1~
TRACKED :     string0~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string2~
NOTICE  : Calling f(string())... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string3*
TRACKED :     string3=>string4*
TRACKED :     string4=>string5*
TRACKED :     string4~
TRACKED :     string3~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string5~
NOTICE  : Constructing s("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string6*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
NOTICE  : Calling f(std::move(s))... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string6=>string7*
TRACKED :     string7=>string8*
TRACKED :     string8=>string9*
TRACKED :     string8~
TRACKED :     string7~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string9~
NOTICE  : Constructing s2("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string10*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
NOTICE  : Calling f(std::move(s))... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string11*(string10)
TRACKED :     string11=>string12*
TRACKED :     string12=>string13*
TRACKED :     string12~
TRACKED :     string11~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string13~
NOTICE  : Leaving main()...
TRACKED : string10~
TRACKED : string6~
```

Which is perfect in terms of copies being made! There is a lot of moving though, which makes me think I might as well just use the good old `std::string const&` (that, if I was using it should be replaced by `std::string_view` I understand-- which I shouldn't be using here since in the end I DO take ownership of the string; as per [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/364094/292220) answer).

Using max66's second suggestion, although I left out the template because I don't think that is needed here? See the different in [this commit](https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-statefultask-testsuite/commit/07269929ee680a100d4bb2755c81fb5fb53dfaa8), the output becomes:

```
NOTICE  : Calling f("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string0*
TRACKED :     string0=>string1*
TRACKED :     string0~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string1~
NOTICE  : Calling f(string())... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string2*
TRACKED :     string2=>string3*
TRACKED :     string2~
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string3~
NOTICE  : Constructing s("test")... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string4*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
NOTICE  : Calling f(std::move(s))... <unfinished>
TRACKED :     string4=>string5*
NOTICE  : <continued> done
TRACKED : string5~
NOTICE  : Leaving main()...
TRACKED : string4~
```

Which it pretty damn close to ideal if it wasn't for the fact
that I had to comment out the passing of the s2 lvalue because
with that I get the error:

`error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘string&&’ to lvalue of type ‘string’`

Is there a way to fix this, so I get the ideal output and still have it work when I try to pass an lvalue? Note that if I add an overload for `f()` that takes a string then the first two calls become ambiguous :(.

Comment: Research "pass by reference"

Comment: The template is an important part of max66's second suggestion. I think you should add it.

Comment: To add some context: It's the template that allows [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) to work. Removing it is what caused the error with the lvalue reference.

Comment: @CássioRenan Ah yes! I added the template and now it's just perfect! Guess I'll accept Max66's answer - cause it won't get any better than that.

Comment: It's why it's called **perfect** forwarding ;). Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You tagged C++17, so you can use move semantics (from C++11) and you use it in `main()`.

It seems to me that the signature, that receive a copy, is OK.

But you have to use `std::move()` inside `f()`

```
Foo * f (std::string s)
 { return new Foo{std::move(s)}; }
// ...............^^^^^^^^^
```

and inside the `Foo()` constructor

```
Foo (std::string s_) : s{std::move(s_)} { }
// ......................^^^^^^^^^
```

or unnecessary copies are made.

An alternative is use template types, universal reference and `std::forward`.

I mean

```
struct Foo
 {
   std::string s;

   template <typename S>
   Foo (S && s_) : s{std::forward<std::string>(s_)} { }
 };

template <typename S>
Foo * f (S && s)
 { return new Foo{std::forward<S>(s)}; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I edited my post with feedback; if you can give me more pointers or comments, please :).

Comment: Ok, sorry - your answer is perfect ;). I shouldn't have removed the templates.